# Angular6 vs Reactjs vs Vuejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, reactjs, vue.js

Give me suggestions on which technology should I learn first.I am new in technology life. Give me your bold suggestions.I will appreciate your suggestions.
I want to use Nodejs as a back-end.Give me advice.

Comment: Learn the javascript first.

Comment: why? Is java script is necessary.

Comment: They are just javascript frameworks. And without knowing js, you're just eating your days to come.

Comment: All these are built in javascript only bro.. first you need a strong understanding in javascript.

Comment: as there is js name of reactjs / vuejs js is necessary for angular6 typescript is necessary which is superset of javascript

Comment: among the 3 of them, Vue is the easiest to learn, React has the highest usage so it's in demand among employers, Angular is the hardest to learn (while having barely any advantages over the 2 other frameworks)

Comment: @JacobGoh Perhpas You are mistaken about usage of React According to the[Survey] (https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/)  Angular is popular and more used than React ;)

Comment: Vikas please guide.

Comment: I think angular is very difficult.

Comment: @Vikas I think the Angular in the survey includes both Angular 1 and Angular 2+. Angular 1 was the leader. Lots of legacy app still use Angular 1. And Angular 2+ is very different from Angular 1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core .

Comment: @Vikas tell me now?

Comment: How much demand of react in europe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make sure you have a good understanding of javascript ( Super Important ! )

coming to your question please refer this, I found it to be good

[REACT JS vs ANGULAR vs VUE](https://2muchcoffee.com/blog/angular-react-vue/)

also please keep in mind there is no best framework, only most suitable framework for the intended project.